# Using WebClient for JSON Serialization?

Tags: c#

I know you can deserialize a **JSON** object from an `HttpWebResponse` using the `WebClient.DownloadString()` but what about the other way around?  I've looked at the MSDN pages and I don't know if you can serialize to JSON objects or not, anyone know?

Comment: Can you provide some sample pseudo code showing what you are trying to do with the WebClient class?

Comment: Serialize JSON so that I can send it via an HttpRequest for consumption of lets say an .ascx or even outside .NET.  Just want to know if it's possible that's all.  I don't see a way.

Answer (score 30):

I think you may just have to serialize the object into JSON before using the WebClient instance. Hope this helps

```
var url = "...";
var json = JsonHelper.ToJson(myObject);

var response = PostJson(url, json);
```

Here's an example of sending JSON data from the WebClient class:

```
public static string PostJson(string url, string data)
{
    var bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(data);

    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
        var response = client.UploadData(url, "POST", bytes);

        return Encoding.Default.GetString(response);
    }
}
```

Here is a simple helper class that uses the `DataContractJsonSerializer` class to serialize / deserialize object to and from JSON.

```
public static class JsonHelper
{
    public static string ToJson<T>(T instance)
    {
        var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
        using (var tempStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            serializer.WriteObject(tempStream, instance);
            return Encoding.Default.GetString(tempStream.ToArray());
        }
    }

    public static T FromJson<T>(string json)
    {
        var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
        using (var tempStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(json)))
        {
            return (T)serializer.ReadObject(tempStream);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but I'm asking about the WebClient object here.  I was trying to figure out if it's possible but do not see anything out there talking about that object being able to serialize...only deserialize.

Answer (score 3):

I use :

```
var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(yourObject);
```