# Post method for HTTP Handler

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have a handler. When I call it with URL that is to say GET method, it works because I get values with my below handler code.

```
var encodedUrl = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(context.Request.QueryString.ToString());
```

How can I get values when I use post method  which is below from Handler side:

```
        using (var wb = new WebClient())
        {
            var data = new NameValueCollection();
            data["a"] = "a";
            data["b"] = "b";

            var response = wb.UploadValues("http://localhost:126/Web", "POST", data);
        }
```

Comment: Is it `context.Request.Form`?..

Comment: I dont understand Anton?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.httprequest.form(v=vs.110).aspx -- Form property of a HttpRequest is a NameValueCollection sent in a query.

Comment: @AntonKovalenko should be correct.  Your `data["a"]` value would be accessed as `var c = context.Request.Form["a"];`

Comment: Check out this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/5401597/182344 for the same question.

Answer (score 0):

When you receive an http response you basically depend on the "Content Type". Depending on this type is that you read it. 
Here is a reference on this topic:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525208(v=vs.90).aspx

For instance if you decide to receive an "application/json" response type. You may be able to use this:

- [Using WebClient for JSON Serialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3391936/using-webclient-for-json-serialization)

From I can see in your sample it looks like you are trying to implement an "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" and the post needs to be formatted accordingly. Here is a sample for that:

1. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.headers(v=vs.110).aspx
2. [How are parameters sent in an HTTP POST request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14551194/how-are-parameters-sent-in-an-http-post-request)

But there are other options available. I hope this is the answer you were looking for.